# Accessing the second content page and calling the function for a specified stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

this is for school project. I have a master page and 2 content pages.

My first content page has 4 buttons. Each buttons correspond to a stored procedure that will be used to access database. My second content page will display the data from the data based based on the button clicked. I am at lost as to which property or data can I use for the session variable to make it happen.

First Content page button "Get Problems By ID" and "Get Problems by Client"

```
   protected void btnProbByProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Contents["ProductID"] = strProduct;
        Response.Redirect("./ReportDisplay.aspx");
    }


   protected void btnProbByClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Contents["Branch"] = strTech;
        Response.Redirect("./ReportDisplay.aspx");
    }
```

Second Content Page has the code below in the Page_Load that depending on the button clicked, it should call the stored procedure associated to the button.

```
  if (Session.Contents["ProductId"] != null)
        {
            GetProblemsByProduct();
        }

        if (Session.Contents["Branch"] != null)
        {
            GetProblemsByClient();
        }
```

Below are my function above.

```
  //******
    private void GetProblemsByProduct()
    {
        lblError.Text = "";
        dsData = clsDatabase.GetProblemsByProduct();
        if (dsData == null)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error retrieving Ticket list1";
        }
        else if (dsData.Tables.Count < 1)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error retrieving Ticket list2";
            dsData.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            gvProb.DataSource = dsData.Tables[0];
            gvProb.DataBind();

            dsData.Dispose();
        }

    }

//****
    private void GetProblemsByClient()
    {
        lblError.Text = "";
        dsData = clsDatabase.GetProblemsByClient();
        if (dsData == null)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error retrieving Ticket list1";
        }
        else if (dsData.Tables.Count < 1)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error retrieving Ticket list2";
            dsData.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            gvProb.DataSource = dsData.Tables[0];
            gvProb.DataBind();

            dsData.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Below are the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspProblemsByProduct]
 AS
--*********************************************************************
 --** Get costs by Product
 --*********************************************************************
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DECLARE @ErrCode int;

 SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfProblems,
   CONVERT(varchar,pr.ProductId) AS ProductId,
   RTRIM(pr.ProductDesc) AS Product, 
   SUM(ISNull((r.Hours * r.CostHours),0) + ISNULL((r.Mileage * 
   r.CostMiles),0) + 
       ISNULL(r.Supplies,0) + ISNULL(r.Misc,0)) AS TotalExpense,
   AVG(ISNull((r.Hours * r.CostHours),0) + ISNULL((r.Mileage * 
  r.CostMiles),0) + 
       ISNULL(r.Supplies,0) + ISNULL(r.Misc,0)) AS AverageExpense
  FROM Problems p
 INNER JOIN Resolutions r ON r.TicketID = p.TicketID AND r.IncidentNo = 
  p.IncidentNo 
  INNER JOIN Products pr ON pr.ProductId = p.ProductId
 GROUP BY pr.ProductId, pr.ProductDesc
 ORDER BY 3;

 SET @ErrCode = @@ERROR;
  SET NOCOUNT OFF;
 RETURN @ErrCode;


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspProblemsByClient]
 AS
--*********************************************************************
--** Get costs by client
--*********************************************************************
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @ErrCode int;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfProblems,
   c.Institution, 
   c.Branch,
   SUM(ISNull((r.Hours * r.CostHours),0) + ISNULL((r.Mileage * 
r.CostMiles),0) + 
       ISNULL(r.Supplies,0) + ISNULL(r.Misc,0)) AS TotalExpense,
   AVG(ISNull((r.Hours * r.CostHours),0) + ISNULL((r.Mileage * 
r.CostMiles),0) + 
       ISNULL(r.Supplies,0) + ISNULL(r.Misc,0)) AS AverageExpense
FROM Problems p
INNER JOIN Resolutions r ON r.TicketID = p.TicketID AND r.IncidentNo = 
p.IncidentNo 
INNER JOIN ServiceEvents se ON se.TicketID = r.TicketID
INNER JOIN Clients c ON c.ClientID = se.ClientID
GROUP BY c.Institution, c.Branch 
ORDER BY 2,3;

SET @ErrCode = @@ERROR;
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
RETURN @ErrCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry cant type in comments yet
>
> In This Code:

```
if (Session.Contents["ProductId"] != null)
        {
            GetProblemsByProduct();
        }

        if (Session.Contents["Branch"] != null)
        {
            GetProblemsByClient();
        }
```

Have you checked that your Id/ Name / Identifier are being sent to the functions? usually params are fed into the Functions inside the ()'s.

> Again I don't have the rep required to comment so I will be just editing this post to respond if it becomes necessary.
>
> > Responses Start Here
> > Hmm... I believe there is a setting that can be turned on that will enable you to "penetrate" into function calls, but you should be able to put breakpoints inside of the functions perhaps on the lines where you do the DB call? see if you are getting data from the DB or if the error is occurring before that populates, if it is populating you can follow the flow from there till you hit the error.

Comment: Hi Royal, Thank you for the info. I did try checking but when I click any button, it checks the parameters in the session content but it skips. :(